# Where is the Terraform CLI configuration file (.terraformrc) located in mac OS?

Tags: terraform, config

The official documentation of terraform mentions that:

[image]

But couldn't find it in my mac.

Macbook version : macOS Big Sur version 11.6.2

Terraform doc : https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/config-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not find it because by default this file does not exist. You can place it in your home folder:

```
cd ~
touch .terraformrc
```

Or you can place it elsewhere and specify the location for it using `TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE` environment variable.